# Can gnuplot create the equivalent of an Rstudio script?

Tags: gnuplot

I am very new to Gnuplot. I have previously used Rstudio, which has a script (which you can write a command and then edit it later and rerun it) and also a console. Does gnuplot have this script equivalent? I notice after writing a command incorrectly I can't delete it. However, I want to save a document only containing correct commands so I can revisiting the code. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course, you can write scripts for gnuplot and save them as a text file and load them in the gnuplot console via `load 'myScript.gp'`. Have you searched the web for gnuplot tutorials? Have you checked this? http://gnuplot.info/

Comment: Issue is I can't delete any of the incorrect code. I have searched the web for tutorials and have looked at the home page but that hasn't yielded the answer I was looking for.

Comment: What do you mean with incorrect code? If you are in the gnuplot console and for example you have typed `set xrange[0:10]; plot x` and you think this was the wrong range and the wrong function then just type `set xrange[2:22]; plot x**2` and you will get a new plot. gnuplot will remember the last valid settings. If you are working with a script in a text file, what is the problem editing a text file and loading this file again? Could you please explain and give an example?

Comment: `Rstudio, which has a script` Rstudio is a IDE, it doesn't "have a script", it simply edits a file. `Does gnuplot have this script equivalent?` No, there is no IDE provided with gnuplot. Use any kind of IDE/tooling/GUI you want.

Comment: Ok thats the answer I was seeing. Thanks Kamil.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot has a "save " command.  The file it produces contains the entire set of commands necessary to reproduce the current state of the program, including the most recent plot.   Most of the commands in the saved file are not relevant to that particular plot, however, because they explicitly set a property to a value that was already the default.  To remove these unneeded commands you can filter the saved file through a script `gpsavediff`, which can be downloaded from the gnuplot web site if you don't already have a copy with your installed version.  The save + filter operation can either be done in two separate steps:

```
  gnuplot> ... lots of stuff including a plot command ...
  gnuplot> save 'myverboseplot.gp'
  gnuplot> exit
  gpsavediff < myverboseplot.gp > myplot.gp
```

or it can be done all once using a piped command:

```
  gnuplot> ... lots of stuff ...
  gnuplot> save '| gpsavediff > myplot.gp'
```

You can further edit the commands in the saved script just as you would any other text document.